# how to get collection results as array with ids

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-collection

it should be simple but I am missing something,
lets say this simple eloquent:

```
Post::select('id')->take(5)->get();
```

I want to get simple array with the results id's so it will look like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

but i am getting something like this:

```
[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"4"},{"id":"5"}]
```

flatten() not working and I am getting the same results:

```
Post::select('id')->take(5)->get()->flatten();
```

> http://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-flatten
>
> The flatten
>   method flattens a multi-dimensional collection into a single
>   dimension:

what i am missing? I remember there is a short line laravel way of getting this results without iterate through the array and create a new one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just got it, its the lists() that do the magic so the answer is:

```
Post::select('id')->take(5)->lists('id');
```

**Update:**
as of laravel 5.2 lists() become [deprecated](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0)

> The lists method on the Collection, query builder and Eloquent query
>   builder objects has been renamed to pluck. The method signature
>   remains the same.

the new method name is pluck which work the same:

```
Post::select('id')->take(5)->pluck('id');
```